# Inject HTTP request in SecurityIdentityAugmentor

Tags: quarkus

Is it possible to inject an HTTP request in a SecurityIdentityAugmentor with Quarkus, so that I can use some HTTP header params to build the augmented identity ?

Comment: This is how to get request in quarkus https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/blob/master/getting-request/src/main/java/com/mascix/GreetingResource.java does it help ?

Comment: Well that example shows how to inject the HTTP request in a REST controller. That's not what I am looking for. I want to inject the HTTP request in SecurityIdentityAugmentor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve an instance of **RoutingContext** from the getAttribute method of **SecurityIdentity**

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomSecurityIdentityAugmentor implements SecurityIdentityAugmentor {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> augment(SecurityIdentity identity, AuthenticationRequestContext context) {
        RoutingContext routingContext = identity.getAttribute(RoutingContext.class.getName());
       logger.tracev("Path {0}", routingContext.request().path());
       return Uni.createFrom().item(identity);
    }
}
```